# How can i start my session in other browser rather than firefox in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium webdriver and by default when i run a script it is opening a session in Firefox. now i want to open this session in other browsers like Google Chrome, IE.

How can i open this sessions?

Thanks 
Kamlesh

Comment: What code you have? You want to run the same script in 3 browsers at the same time?

Comment: I want to run same script in different browsers at different time.

Comment: what code you have to run in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome

1 - Download chromedriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com

2 - Extract to a location on your machine

3 - Use following code to change your test webdriver to chrome

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\path\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

For Internet Explorere, do the similar steps above, but

1 - Download IEdriver from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0.zip (If you use windows 64 bits, then download http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0.zip)

2 - Extract to a location on your machine

3 - Use following code to change your test webdriver to IE

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "c:\\path\\IEdriver.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```